# Différence entre l'oral et l'écrit concernant l'emploi de « pas » et de « non »

Tags: grammaire, négation, adverbes, oral

> Une lettre non reçue peut avoir des graves conséquences.

Les livres de grammaire disent que devant un adjectif, un participe ou un adverbe (non loin) il faut employer non.
Cependant l'usage (surtout l'oral) prefère pas

> pas reçue, pas loin

Pourquoi cette différence ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je pense que ceci est l'une des richesses de la langue française qui possède plusieurs registres (niveau de langue).

Utiliser « pas » est plus familier, plus usuel et plus oral que « non » dans la majorité des cas.
On dit plus souvent « pas » à l'oral et c'est aussi très utilisé à l'écrit. Au contraire, on entendra plus rarement non loin à l'oral et on le lira plus.

Ces deux adverbes expriment donc la négation dans deux registres de langage différents : **courant** pour « pas » et **soutenu** pour « non ».
Il existe une page wikipédia à propos des différents registres de langues :
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registre_de_langue
English : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(sociolinguistics)

Notez qu'il existe d'autres natures grammaticales pour exprimer la négation autre que les adverbes « non » et « pas » :
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%A9gation_(linguistique)#Nature_grammaticale

Comment: Le fait que *pas reçue* soit d'un registre courant s'explique par le fait que *non reçue* est suffisant pour exprimer la négation tandis que *pas* requiers *ne* dans un registre soutenu (*Une lettre qui **n**'est pas reçue peut avoir...)